# Installed magento 2.3 CE with sample on windows 10 using Xampp

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, windows

Installed **magento 2.3 CE** with sample on windows 10 using Xampp. Installation was completed but after clicking on the **"Go to admin"** shows **blank screen**. please help

Answer (score 0):

Try editing the *Validator file* from **`vendor`** folder with namespace

> **vendor\magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\File\Validator.php**

At around line **138** replace code with this one

```
$realPath = str_replace('\\', '/',$this->fileDriver->getRealPath($path));
```

save then run **cache:flush**